# tomcat is not starting up when running app

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat8

this is pom xml
i have main class and one simple controller which returns string as json.
i am just running spring boot 2.x by adding below dependency.
in console it shows tomcat is started and application is started.but when i am hitting from postman or url in browser it will 404.

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.kd</groupId>
<artifactId>restdemo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>restdemo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

this is my controller:

```
package com.kd.controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ServiceControllerKd {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public Hello greeting() {
     System.out.println("hello");
     return new Hello();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your controller routing? Do you have any?

Comment: May be you can post your controller and the url you posted.

Comment: have you tried `localhost:8080/health`

Comment: What's the contents of the Hello.java class?

Comment: class Hello { Stirng s="hello"; }

Comment: my issue is tomcat not starting up

Comment: any error or log trace?

Comment: Your class hello needs getters, setters, and a no args constructor. Also, are you running this from within your IDE or from a jar/war?

Comment: i am using springboot 2.x and i have specified :  server.port=9090
server.servlet.context-path=/hello

Comment: in pom i have spec. :  <start-class>com.kd.RestdemoApplication</start-class>

Comment: now its calling main class still tomcat is not started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken your code, built it, ran it and hit the endpoint and have successfully received a response. However, it is difficult to assess what may be causing your issue without the full project.

I have created an example project using the code you provided here that runs successfully. It may be best to compare this project against your own to attempt to find any inconsistencies.

https://github.com/michaelmcfadyen/spring-boot-example

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you must first try to return a single string

**example**:
`return "Hello world!"`

To make sure that the problem is not from your Hello object.

Another thing that you have to make sure is that you have the right port on the postman request example `http://localhost:8000/` and that your method on post man get the right verb, in your case you can add

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
and it's gonna be a "get".
```

Answer (score 0):

double check that you have your controller in the same package as your SpringBootApplication or in a child package

```
package com.kd;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication  
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

In the log you have to see something similar to

```
2018-07-28 12:34:01.669  INFO 10425 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto java.lang.String com.kd.controller.ServiceControllerKd.greeting()
```

Comment: By "packete" you mean "package" I suppose?